# Rolling minimum of an array so that first values are minimum of window, not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rolling-computation

So far I've been panda'fying my array so that I can use the Panda's rolling + min() features, I'm using a window of window of width 3.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

q = np.array([ 4.71858472,  4.5252853 ,  3.43745458,  1.978533  , -0.50446801,
   -0.25213346,  0.04942399, -0.76639228,  0.17852748,  0.58374693])

df_q = pd.DataFrame(q,columns=['min_q'])

df_min = df_q.rolling(3,min_periods=1).min()
```

What I'm getting is that Pandas inserts NaN values for the first 2 returned values (makes sense) if `min_periods` aren't specified, or when specified it takes only the specified values (makes sense too). What I would like to know is if it's possible to get a returned series where initial values of the returned set are equal to the lowest of the first window, not the values of the minimum periods.

What I'm getting:

```
array([[ 4.71858472], [ 4.5252853 ],[ 3.43745458],[ 1.978533  ],[-0.50446801],[-0.50446801],[-0.50446801],[-0.76639228],[-0.76639228],[-0.76639228]])
```

What I want:

```
array([[ 3.43745458], [ 3.43745458 ],[ 1.978533],[ 0.50446801 ],[-0.50446801],[-0.50446801],[-0.76639228],[-0.76639228],[-0.76639228],[0.17852748]])
```

Is this even possible to do in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html#pandas-dataframe-bfill)

```py
>>> df_min = df_q.rolling(3).min().bfill()
>>> df_min
      min_q
0  3.437455
1  3.437455
2  3.437455
3  1.978533
4 -0.504468
5 -0.504468
6 -0.504468
7 -0.766392
8 -0.766392
9 -0.766392
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for performance, you can use [scipy.ndimage.filters.minimum_filter1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.minimum_filter1d.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.ndimage.filters import minimum_filter1d

q = np.array([ 4.71858472,  4.5252853 ,  3.43745458,  1.978533  , -0.50446801,
   -0.25213346,  0.04942399, -0.76639228,  0.17852748,  0.58374693])

def rolling_scipy(a, W):
    hW = (W-1)//2 
    out = minimum_filter1d(a, size=W, origin=hW)
    out[:W-1] = out[W-1]
    return out

%timeit rolling_scipy(q, 3)
12.8 µs ± 1.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

def rolling_pandas(a, W):
    df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['min_q'])
    return df.rolling(W).min().bfill()

%timeit rolling_pandas(q, W)
1.41 ms ± 146 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```